# Why do i need press twice to display the element 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, if-statement

I want to press one time to display all the elements,

why I should press two times to display the 0 elements?

I try to order the if statements but I didn't figure it out.

here is the link [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HamzaSamiHussein1_/96hr3fcp/)

```
var words = ['rainbow', 'heart', 'purple', 'friendship', 'love'];
  function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
  }
  function draw() {
    background(0);
  
    textSize(32);
    text(words[i]);
  
  }
  function mousePressed() {
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

      text(words[i], 100, i * 50 + 50);
      if (i == 0) {
        fill(255, 0, 0);
      }

      if (i == 1 ) {
        fill(0, 50, 100, 300);
      }
      if (i == 2) {
        fill(0, 165, 300, 200);
      }
      if (i == 3) {
        fill(0, 50, 100, 300);
      }

      if (i == 4) {
        fill(0, 50, 100, 300);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Since you are using ==, change "if" to "else if" for all ifs testing == 1 to == 4, or insert a "return;" after each fill() call.

Comment: I would recommend changing the words array to array of object. Each object would contain the word, and fill options. This way it will be much easier to add words to the list and keeping everything organized.

Comment: @Akxe can you give me an example of how I can do this in my code, please?

Comment: @SPlatten I'd use switch-case.

Comment: @TimTimWong, Why **switch-case** is better than **else-if statements** ?

Comment: @HamzaSAMI The runtime can then optimize it like array indexing.

Comment: @TimTimWong, Can you plz explain in a simpler way, I am a beginner in this field.

Comment: @HamzaSAMI No, optimization is too complicated for beginners.

Comment: For some reason, you're relying on an error thrown at `text(words[i])` in `draw()`.

Comment: @HamzaSAMI See how I use array index to pick the color in my updated answer?

Comment: yeah, I know it shows me an error, how to fix it?
@TimTimWong

Comment: @HamzaSAMI fixed in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219207/discussion-between-timtim-wong-and-hamza-sami).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `fill()` was not called before the first `text()`. By the way, drawing code should reside in `draw()`.

```js
const words = ['rainbow', 'heart', 'purple', 'friendship', 'love'],
    colors = [
        [255, 0, 0],
        [0, 50, 100, 300],
        [0, 165, 300, 200],
        [0, 50, 100, 300],
        [0, 50, 100, 300],
    ];
let isMousePressed = false;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}
function draw() {
    background(0);
    textSize(32);
    if (isMousePressed)
        words.forEach((w, i) => {
            fill.call(null, colors[i]);
            text(w, 100, (i + 1) * 50);
        });
}
function mousePressed() {
    isMousePressed = true;
}
```

Comment: So you are saying, that we should call first the textColor which is in our case is **fill()**,  and then we implement the color to the **text**, that makes sense I guess, right?

Comment: @HamzaSAMI Default fill is transparent black, so you were drawing with no color.

Comment: But imagine if fill() is used for coloring, my assumption is right?

Comment: @HamzaSAMI It's not like draw the text and then fill it, but set the current fill color and then draw text with the current fill color.

Answer (score 0):

Credits for solving goes to @TimTimWong, I am just explaining a comment I made.

```
const words = [
  {
    word: 'rainbow',
    colors: [255, 0, 0],
  },
  {
    word: 'heart',
    colors: [0, 50, 100, 300],
  },
  {
    word: 'purple',
    colors: [0, 165, 300, 200],
  },
  {
    word: 'friendship',
    colors: [0, 50, 100, 300],
  },
  {
    word: 'love',
    colors: [0, 50, 100, 300],
  }
];
let isMousePressed = false;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}
function draw() {
  background(0);
  textSize(32);
  if (isMousePressed) {
    words.forEach(({ word, color }, i) => {
      fill.call(null, color);
      text(word, 100, (i + 1) * 50);
    });
  }
}
function mousePressed() {
  isMousePressed = true;
}
```